# Replace backslash when in path but not escape character

Tags: regex

We have a larger project where almost all include file paths are written using the "Windows style" backslash syntax, e.g `include 'foo\bar.baz'`. Now we would like to run the poject on Unix machines as well, however we are (obviously) having trouble regarding the backslashes in the path names. 
Unfortunately I cannot replace all backslashes with forward slashes as they are used for creating newlines `\n` and escaping characters in other parts of the code.

I tried fiddling around with RegEx in order to match the backslash character only when enclosed by quotation marks

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

and followed by either another backslash or a dot. But the above only find the text within the quotation marks, and I'm stuck on how to get it to only match the slash inside it.

Thanks a lot for your help!

P.S.: I use Atom as an editor if this is of any help

Comment: I have no solution but a suggestion: instead of replacing the file separator from win to unix, you should use a constant like in java File.pathSeparator (but there are in may languages). This should help in the future. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately we are already using the constant for the Graphical User Interface (in Java), however the largest part of the project is written in the Algebraic Modeling Language GAMS (as it is an economic model), which does not feature such a constant

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/U0MboP/1

```
(["'])(.+)\\\\?(.+)\1
```

This regex

And this replace https://regex101.com/r/U0MboP/2

```
\1\2/\3\1
```

Comment: Weren't they wanting to replace the backslashes with forward slashes?  Wouldn't this make the substitution `\1\2/\4\1`?

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your answers! @Froopy was right about the replacement, however, I just realized the problem is a little more complex: Every now and then there are strings which encapsulate the newline `\n`, and also sometimes paths contain more than one slash, I updated the example from @Piterden and will also fiddle around with it, again thanks for your contributions so far [link](https://regex101.com/r/U0MboP/3)

Comment: @ChristophPahmeyer, you could try scrubbing all newlines from the given string since you're only looking for what's in between tics.